# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "Execution reverted", "data": "0x" }

Tags: web3js, metamask, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

After getting the contract I tried to call a function from the deployed contract Address. But it is giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "Execution reverted",
  "data": "0x"
}
```

I tried to call the following function:
`await contractInstance.methods.RESERVE_NFT().call();`

Comment: Do you have ABI by which you call the contract function?